# Access parent site library content from child site

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-library

I am working on a project where I have built a Parent site and it has document library called "All Project Documents". In that site I have sub sites called 'Project A', 'Project B' and 'Project c'. I want to access the content of All Projects Documents from Project A, Project b and Project B site.

Some key information:
I am using SharePoint online 2016.
It does not provide straight away option to export web parts.
2013 SharePoint Designer 2013 does not provide design view from where we can export the web parts.

Many Thanks

Comment: Please try this and see if it works in SP Online/2016: https://chuvash.eu/2014/09/19/export-any-web-part-from-a-sharepoint-page/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Content Query Webpart(Content Rollup-> Content Query Webpart). And the details are as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Content Search Web Part.  When setting up the query, point it to the URL of the document library on the parent site.

If this information helped, please mark as answer or vote up.